# mocking all classes from a module in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a test_a.py, a.py and b.py in 3 different directories in my test environment.

b.py

```
class SBD():

def __init__(self):
    print("SBD created (In B)")
```

a.py

```
import b
from b import *

print("In module A")

def fun1():
  a=SBD()
  print("SBD created(In A)")
```

test_a.py

```
import unittest
import sys
from unittest.mock import Mock,patch,MagicMock

sys.path.append("../abc/")
import b as c
sys.modules['b'] = MagicMock(spec=c)

sys.path.append("../xyz/")
import a

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_isupper(self):
        a.fun1()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In a real situation, b.py will have multiple classes and I wanted to mock all of them, so I tried mocking the module b with the same specifications. But when i run the test_a.py it gives me an error saying "SBD" is not defined. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `MagicMock` instance does not provide the same information to the import machinery as a module would. Even with a `spec`, there is no actual `SDB` attribute defined on the mock, so `from b import *` won't find it.

The `from *` import machinery tries two different things:

- It tries to access the name `__all__`; if defined it must be a list of strings of names to import.
- If `__all__` is not defined, the keys of the `__dict__` attribute are taken, filtering out names that start with an underscore.

Because your `b` module has no `__all__` list defined, the `__dict__` keys are taken instead. For a `MagicMock` instance specced against a module, the `__dict__` attribute only consists of names with `_` underscores and the `mock_calls` attribute. `from b import *` only imports `mock_calls`:

```
>>> import a as c
>>> module_mock = MagicMock(spec=c)
>>> [n for n in module_mock.__dict__ if n[:1] != '_']
['method_calls']
```

I would strongly advice *against* mocking the whole module; doing this would require that you postpone importing `a`, and is *fragile*. The patch is permanent (is not undone automatically when tests end) and won't support repeated runs of the test or running tests in random order.

But if you *had* to make this work, you could add a `__all__` attribute to the mock first:

```
sys.modules['b'] = MagicMock(spec=c, __all__=[n for n in c.__dict__ if n[:1] != '_'])
```

Personally, I'd a) avoid using `from module import *` syntax altogether. If I could not prevent this from being used anyway, the next step would be to apply patches to `a` *after* importing, looping over the `b` module to obtain specced replacements:

```
# avoid manipulating sys.path if at all possible. Move that to a PYTHONPATH
# variable or install the modules properly.
import unittest
from unittest import mock

import a
import b

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # mock everything `from b import *` would import
        b_names = getattr(b, '__all__', None)
        if b_names is None:
            b_names = [n for n in b.__dict__ if n[:1] != '_']
        self.b_mocks = {}
        for name in b_names:
            orig = getattr(b, name, None)
            if orig is None:
                continue
            self.b_mocks[name] = mock.patch.object(a, name, spec=orig)
            self.b_mocks[name].start()
            self.addCleanup(self.b_mocks[name].stop)

    def test_isupper(self):
        a.fun1()
```

This leaves `sys.modules['b']` untouched, and processes the exact same names that `from *` would load. The patches are *removed* again after the test ends.

The above test outputs:

```
$ python test_a.py
In module A
SBD created(In A)
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```